# DTS pkg converted to SSIS failing due to truncation issue

Tags: ssis, truncate, dts, truncation

I am having an issue where I need to bring DTS pkgs to a new server and have them run as a scheduled SQL job. I have gone into the DTS pkg and edited the connections to include the new 2008 server name and the new UNC paths. The DTS package takes a flat file with fixed lengths and loads those values into a db table. After editing the DTS, I export out to structured DTS package file. I then go to the new server and use the migration wizard to turn the DTS into DTSX file. Once that is done, I import the DTSX into integration services with protection level at "Rely on server storage and roles for access control".

I then run the package and it is failing for the following reason:

```
Source: Copy Data from Medical Services to  cabinet   dbo   SERVICE_FILE  Task Flat File Source [1]    


 Description: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Col004" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.". 


 End Error  Error: 2013-03-04 23:19:13.01     Code: 0xC020902A     Source: Copy Data from Medical Services to  cabinet   dbo   SERVICE_FILE  Task Flat File Source [1]     Description: The "output column "Col004" (22)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Col004" (22)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  End Error  Error: 2013-03-04 23:19:13.01     Code: 0xC0202092     Source: Copy Data from Medical Services to  cabinet   dbo   SERVICE_FILE  Task Flat File Source [1]     Description: An error occurred while processing file "\\hpf15release\global$\cold\coldin\FTP_DXPX\Medical_Services_Master_File" on data row 1.  End Error  Error: 2013-03-04 23:19:13.01     Code: 0xC0047038     Source: Copy Data from Medical Services to  cabinet   dbo   SERVICE_FILE  Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Flat File Source" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:19:12 PM  Finished: 11:19:13 PM  Elapsed:  0.952 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

I am using the same package ...and flat file as was used in the old server and it works fine on the old server. The table it is trying to copy to has the same columns with same characteristics...so trying to understand where this error is coming from.

Any help MUCH appreciated

Comment: 1)You edit your original DTS package to make a reference to the new location. 2) You run it through the migration wizard to convert to SSIS? Is the end result a proper SSIS package or is it an SSIS package that simply has the "Execute DTS package" step in it?

Comment: I think it is the Execute DTS package most likely as when I open it in visual studio, everyline begins with <DTS:Property DTS:Name=...etc etc

Comment: When I opened the DTS package on the 2008 server in the editor and execute it, it works flawlessly. However if I export the package to desktop as DTS, then use migration wizard to convert to DTSX and then import that pkg into integration services and then run it...this is when it fails

Answer (score 0):

please check your destination table structure if it is same as previous. it may the datatype issue. I had the same issue before and fixed it by datatype conversion.